# Best way to do this simple technique with Angular?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm looking for best practices.

Basically I'd like it so that if you click on a nav button, a drop down would **slide down**.

So I have :

```
= link_to 'lez see the dropdown!', '#', 'ng-click' => 'open_dropdown()'
```

Then I have in my controller..

```
$scope.open_dropdown = ->
```

But when I reference `this`, it pulls up an Angular object that doesn't allow you to access the DOM.

**my html**

```
<div class="span1">
  <a class="icon settings" ng-click="open_dropdown()" href="#"></a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    Secret drop down stuffs!
  </div>
</div>
```

So I think I have it worked out ( sort of ) how to hide/show Angular-style where you place a value for `ng-show` on `.dropdown`, but I don't want it show. Its gotta *slide*.

Even more so, I'd like to make it so that if you click somewhere else, it goes away. Typically I can write all of this in jQuery in 6 lines. But Angular acts like a proprietary gated community, so I feel like I should be taking advantage of the koolaid at hand here.

**The Question**

How does one make a dropdown slide down in the most Angular way?

Comment: I don't even know how to do this with plain jquery.  Could you share non-angular version of the code?

Answer (score 2):

CSS is your friend:

```
<a ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen">open</a>
<div class="dropdown" ng-class="{ open: isOpen }">
    dropdown stuff
</div>


.dropdown {
    height: 0;
    transition: height 0.5s ease-in;
    /* vendor prefixes needed as well, see fiddle below */
}
.dropdown.open {
    height: 200px;
     /* I think "height: auto" should work, too */
}
```

If you need even more control, look into creating your own Directive for this functionality. Or see if you can find one in Angular-UI or elsewhere.

---

**Update**

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4HhQ8/1/). I also tested with `height: auto;` and it worked, but the padding transition didn't animate properly, at least in Chrome. If you can use a specified height, it'll animate a little better, but I realize that isn't always ideal. I even threw in an opacity change in the transition -- it works just as well without, but personally I like the look of it.

(P.S. [css3please.com](http://css3please.com/) is a great source to quickly check which browser prefixes are necessary for the most common css3 rules. That's where I got all my transition rules from.)

Comment: As far as I know only pixel values allow for transitions in css at the moment. Height auto should work but the nice effect is gone :)

Comment: Thanks Keith! This doesn't actually do anything. Maybe because I have to instantiate the logic with a controller? I also have `display: none` as a value for `.dropdown`

Comment: yeah, you'll have to drop the display: none. Height will be a little funny if there's top or bottom padding too. I was posting from a tablet yesterday, let me see if I can work something up in a jsFiddle now that I've got a keyboard in front of me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use CSS translate property in conjunction with ngShow directive of angular JS. Angular does not provide animation effects but angular UI might provide you that.